# Anjuta configuration for GNOME Javascript application development

Tags: javascript, gnome, gjs, anjuta

I trying to run a [GNOME JavaScript application tutorial in Anjuta](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/record-collection.js.html.en).:

```
const GLib = imports.gi.GLib;
const Gtk = imports.gi.Gtk;
const Gda = imports.gi.Gda;
const Lang = imports.lang;

function Demo () {
  this._init ();
}

Demo.prototype = {

  _init: function () {
    this.setupWindow ();
    this.setupDatabase ();
    this.selectData ();
  },

  setupWindow: function () {
    this.window = new Gtk.Window ({title: "Data Access Demo", height_request: 350});
    this.window.connect ("delete-event", function () { 
      Gtk.main_quit();
      return true;
      });

    // main box
    var main_box = new Gtk.Box ({orientation: Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing: 5});
    this.window.add (main_box);

    // first label
    var info1 = new Gtk.Label ({label: "<b>Insert a record</b>", xalign: 0, use_markup: true});
    main_box.pack_start (info1, false, false, 5);

    // "insert a record" horizontal box
    var insert_box = new Gtk.Box ({orientation: Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing: 5});
    main_box.pack_start (insert_box, false, false, 5);

    // ID field
    insert_box.pack_start (new Gtk.Label ({label: "ID:"}), false, false, 5);
    this.id_entry = new Gtk.Entry ();
    insert_box.pack_start (this.id_entry, false, false, 5);

    // Name field
    insert_box.pack_start (new Gtk.Label ({label: "Name:"}), false, false, 5);
    this.name_entry = new Gtk.Entry ({activates_default: true});
    insert_box.pack_start (this.name_entry, true, true, 5);

    // Insert button
    var insert_button = new Gtk.Button ({label: "Insert", can_default: true});
    insert_button.connect ("clicked", Lang.bind (this, this._insertClicked));
    insert_box.pack_start (insert_button, false, false, 5);
    insert_button.grab_default ();

    // Browse textview
    var info2 = new Gtk.Label ({label: "<b>Browse the table</b>", xalign: 0, use_markup: true});
    main_box.pack_start (info2, false, false, 5);
    this.text = new Gtk.TextView ({editable: false});
    var sw = new Gtk.ScrolledWindow ({shadow_type:Gtk.ShadowType.IN});
    sw.add (this.text);
    main_box.pack_start (sw, true, true, 5);

    this.count_label = new Gtk.Label ({label: "", xalign: 0, use_markup: true});
    main_box.pack_start (this.count_label, false, false, 0);

    this.window.show_all ();
  },

  setupDatabase: function () {
    this.connection = new Gda.Connection ({provider: Gda.Config.get_provider("SQLite"),
                                           cnc_string:"DB_DIR=" + GLib.get_home_dir () + ";DB_NAME=gnome_demo"});
    this.connection.open ();

    try {
      var dm = Gda.execute_select_command (this.connection, "select * from demo");
    } catch (e) {
      Gda.execute_non_select_command (this.connection, "create table demo (id integer, name varchar(100))");
    }
  },

  selectData: function () {
    var dm = Gda.execute_select_command (this.connection, "select * from demo order by 1, 2");
    var iter = dm.create_iter ();

    var text = "";

    while (iter.move_next ()) {
      var id_field = Gda.value_stringify (iter.get_value_at (0));
      var name_field = Gda.value_stringify (iter.get_value_at (1));

      text += id_field + "\t=>\t" + name_field + '\n';
    }

    this.text.buffer.text = text;
    this.count_label.label = "<i>" + dm.get_n_rows () + " record(s)</i>";
  },

  _showError: function (msg) {
    var dialog = new Gtk.MessageDialog ({message_type: Gtk.MessageType.ERROR,
                                         buttons: Gtk.ButtonsType.CLOSE,
                                         text: msg,
                                         transient_for: this.window,
                                         modal: true,
                                         destroy_with_parent: true});
    dialog.run ();
    dialog.destroy ();
  },

  _insertClicked: function () {
    if (!this._validateFields ())
      return;

    // Gda.execute_non_select_command (this.connection, "insert into demo values ('" + this.id_entry.text + "', '" + this.name_entry.text + "')");

    var b = new Gda.SqlBuilder ({stmt_type:Gda.SqlStatementType.INSERT});
    b.set_table ("demo");
    b.add_field_value_as_gvalue ("id", this.id_entry.text);
    b.add_field_value_as_gvalue ("name", this.name_entry.text);
    var stmt = b.get_statement ();
    this.connection.statement_execute_non_select (stmt, null);

    this._clearFields ();
    this.selectData ();
  },

  _validateFields: function () {
    if (this.id_entry.text == "" || this.name_entry.text == "") {
      this._showError ("All fields are mandatory");
      return false;
    }
    if (isNaN (parseInt (this.id_entry.text))) {
      this._showError ("Enter a number");
      this.id_entry.grab_focus ();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  },

  _clearFields: function () {
    this.id_entry.text = "";
    this.name_entry.text = "";
    this.id_entry.grab_focus ();
  }
}

Gtk.init (null, null);

var demo = new Demo ();

Gtk.main ();
```

but I get the following error.:

```
EXECUTING:
/home/buzz-dee/flextime-tracker/src/main.js 
----------------------------------------------
/home/buzz-dee/flextime-tracker/src/main.js: Zeile 1: const: Kommando nicht gefunden.
/home/buzz-dee/flextime-tracker/src/main.js: Zeile 2: const: Kommando nicht gefunden.
/home/buzz-dee/flextime-tracker/src/main.js: Zeile 3: const: Kommando nicht gefunden.
/home/buzz-dee/flextime-tracker/src/main.js: Zeile 4: const: Kommando nicht gefunden.
/home/buzz-dee/flextime-tracker/src/main.js: Zeile 7: Syntaxfehler beim unerwarteten Wort `;'
/home/buzz-dee/flextime-tracker/src/main.js: Zeile 7: `  this._init ();'

----------------------------------------------
Program exited with errcode (2)
Press the Enter key to close this terminal ...
```

In Anjuta I have the following settings for the JavaScript environment.:

[image: Anjuta JavaScript environment settings]

I'm using AntergOS (Arch Linux). Maybe the **Gir** and **Gjs** paths are not correct, because I get an error about: `const: Command not found`?

What could be the problem for the above error?

I found a related problem for Anjuta Java project: [How to import an existing Java project in the Anjuta IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617645/how-to-import-an-existing-java-project-in-the-anjuta-ide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that:

```
#!/usr/bin/gjs
```

was missing in the first line of the `main.js` file.